# How do I export from an HTML table to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-drive-api

~[Opposite of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775476/converting-google-spreadsheet-to-html-table)

I'm working with the google drive javascript API, and I've used it to add a "Save to Drive" button in my web application. With this save to drive button, it requires you to give the location of the file in order for it to be downloaded. Let me explain the page

There is an html form, and you fill out the fields and click "Check", it queries the database, parses those results into an html table that can be viewed from the webpage. The results aren't saved to a file. There's not enough space to scale a solution that saves these reports and keeps them on the server. **To be clear here I am looking for being able to provide a downloadable spreadsheet generated from the html table.**

There is [webViewLink](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html), but this implies that a file exists. Using PHP or javascript to make a temporary file out of the html data could work -- if there is no html to google spreadsheet converter, an html to spreadsheet parser would do the trick. But I'm trying to do this with as little custom coding as possible, as it is part of a larger project and I shouldn't get stuck on coding things that might already have robust solutions.

Even it being google drive isn't all that important. Are there other libraries that would make it easy to download html tables as spreadsheets? The reason I'm asking for a quick solution like a library is that this isn't a main feature of my project, otherwise I'd spend a bit of time on it. It's just something shiny that I can show got done during the timeframe, because higher ups don't appreciate back end refactoring as much as they should.

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) might work, but I get the feeling it will use storage on the server. The old system of copy pasting the data to a spreadsheet works too, but I'm trying to make it one-click, bam, excel sheet, without having to ask for a bigger VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to download an excel spreadsheet. Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/)

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Have a look here too.](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/11/exporting-html-table-data-to-excel-file.html) Next time, try widening your search criteria.

Comment: I don't understand `'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'` or how to change the name of the file that is downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You could try Excel Online. This has a JavaScript API.
See http://microsoft-office-add-ins.com for more information.